# What is the difference between > and >> in batch

Tags: batch-file

I am having problems with `>>` and I have seen people use `>` but I don't know the difference.

I Google searched and went through all 45 results and all results were off topic. I even searched on here and no results about the difference.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: The characters `<` `>` are redirection. How they are used is to either redirect an output stream to a file or from a file. By streams we mean typical `stdout` and `stderr`. So you can redirect only `stdout` to a file and overwrite the file each time plus create the file if non existant. as `>file` or do the same but for `stderr` as `2>file` or redirect `stderr` to `stdout` and then `stdout` to file (including `stderr`) as `>file 2>&1`. The same apply reading from `stdin` `<file` etc. Doubling up these simply appends the content below the existing content yet still creates the file if not exist

Answer (score 2):

`>` overwrites a file, `>>` appends to the end of a file.

Answer (score 1):

Both operators create a new file, if it does not exist. If the file exists, there's a difference between `>` and `>>`:
In that case `>` replaces the existing file, whereas `>>` appends to the existing file.